# .net botframework There was an error sending this message to your bot

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework

I have a simple chatbot setup. It works locally in the emulator, I also have it published on Azure and that also works with the emulator using authentication.

My problem is that if I go to https://dev.botframework.com/bots and select my bot and click Test, then type in a message, it always says - *Couldn't send retry*, and the webchat channel shows an issue with the error. *There was an error sending this message to your bot*.

I've also setup a web page with web chat on it which also doesn't return any messages, it just accepts my input. Each of these then corresponds to a new entry as above stating that - *there was an error sending this message to your bot*.

I've tried every suggestion I can find, including updating from nuget (nothing to update), checking the clock on the PC, using

`curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MySecret&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"`

which works as expected. I've setup appinsights in the hope that would catch something but it doesn't even see the messages, though I'm not very familiar with it so may have missed something.

As suggested by @JasonSowers i have tested it in Skype too and that says it sent the message but nothing else happens (no retry message, and no response). I've also checked the MSAppId and MSAppPassword (I copied them from web.config to the emulator, the emulator is the only place it works)

I've completely run out of troubleshooting ideas and am particularly confused by the fact that the emulator works but the one on https://dev.botframework.com/bots doesn't. Any suggestions would be gratefully recieved.

Comment: I think this is a bug with Web Chat. What happens when you click the link that says retry? If sending the message successful it's just a bug within Web Chat. Checkout this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3304)

Comment: Is it working on any channel other than the emulator or the test panel?

Comment: hitting rety on the test panel just repeats the issue ie I get Couldn't send retry again. I must admit I've not tried another channel, I'll take a look at that

Comment: Does the web.config have the correct MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword for the published bot?  What is your BotId?

Comment: the bot id is WasteBotNEL. I copied the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword from web.config into the emulator and the emulator works